# Metrics in Heroku free tier

Tags: heroku

I'm a student and I have deployed a Telegram bot on Heroku's free tier which used by some students of my university. It would be better if I could see my bot's metrics to improve it more. I know I can upgrade to a paid Dyno to view metrics but currently I'm not in a position to do a such thing so is there a way to view app's metrics in Heroku's free tier?

Comment: Specifically, what do you mean by "metrics"?

Comment: Dear friend, I have the same question. So I've been searched for a lot of time the way to get free metrics, but couldn't find anything. I think the easyest way is to pay some money and get all tools heroku included

Comment: @Chris "Metrics" tab in Heroku app dashboard. In there I think you can view ram and CPU usage and other insights.

Comment: @vovakirdan Try Render.com. It allows to view metrics in their free tier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to view metrics in Heroku's free tier but found an alternative which is [Render.com](https://render.com/). At the time of writing this render.com allows users' to view metrics in their free tier.